# How to remove redundant encapsulating curly brackets from json?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON object in C# that unfortunately is being returned like this:

```
var obj = 
{{
    answer: {
             one: "my answer one"
             two: "my answer two"
             }
}};
```

I want to be able to go like this:

```
string answerOne = obj.answer.one;
```

Since the outside curly brackets are present I am able to access my fields inside answer.  How can I remove these or access the inside fields?

Comment: In javascript ?

Comment: C# sorry forgot to specify

Comment: You say "C#", but write JavaScript code.

Comment: Sorry it's a little off.  My obj comes from the server and stored into a var.  Then I am trying to access the fields in that var.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can just index the outer object at 0. Like this jsonRes[0] that should bring it down one more level. Set a var jRes =obj[0]; then jRes.answer.one

Comment: What you've shown is neither valid JSON nor valid JavaScript. How can this "object" be "stored into a var" if the browser can't even parse it? I think something is missing here. How is this response being generated? What is the actual data being served in the response? What does the code that requests and handles it look like?

Answer (score 2):

You could clean the string using the **[String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)** method :

```
obj = obj.Replace("{{", "{"); // Replace the left curly braces
obj = obj.Replace("}}", "}"); // Replace the right curly braces
```

Comment: exactly you don't need to actually remove, you can replace

Answer (score 0):

This looks not a valid json string, I doubt any Json parser could deserialize it back to a object. If it happens to all API request, You'd better to ask your server developer to fix this bug. If you don't have control of that, You may need to write a HttpModule, to pre-process the Request.Body, sanify the data.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid Json.

Have a look at [this](http://json.org/).

If you have a **string**,look like this:

```
"{{
    answer: {
             one: "my answer one"
             two: "my answer two"
             }
}}"
```

you may replace `"{{"` and `"}}"` to `"{"` and `"}"`,and then you can parse it.

Answer (score 0):

it is a JObject.

```cs
JObject foo=JObject.parse(obj); //parse if it is string
var temp=(JObject)foo;
var answerone=temp["answer"]["one"]; //my answer one
```